# java robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK); не нажимается правая кнопка

Tags: java

Такая проблема, не знаю в чем соль. Для теста, в программе надо сделать имитацию нажатия правой кнопки мыши, чтобы перейти в определенную форму.
Есть код снизу, в нем я перемещаю курсор и нажимаю сначала правую кнопку мыши, потом два раза левую.

Вопрос: почему мышка перемещается, но правая кнопка не нажимается(может программно она и нажимается, но контекстное меню не появляется - когда вручную щелкаю правой кнопкой - появляется).

Сижу в intellij idea + selenium + testng(просто информация).
Пробовал также: 
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK); 
Объявить в начале класса робота: static Robot robot = null;

```
   robot.mouseMove(605,239);               
   robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);          
   robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);        
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   robot.mouseMove(711,275);

    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    robot.mouseMove(950,300);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем я не понял как это работает, но сработало вот так.

```
  robot.mouseMove(605,239);               
   robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK); 
     robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
     robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);         
   robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
```